# How I can handle JSON data from ajax request in Jersey API

Tags: ajax, jersey

I have this ajax request below:

```js
var data = {
   id: 5,
   name: 'Bilbo Baggins',
   age: '27'
};

$.post('/editHim', data, function(returnedData) {
   followTheDragonWithTheRing(returnedData);
});
```

And I´m trying to handle 'data' with the Jersey API. I am looking for a response in the documents and all I saw is methods to extract data from path or querystring.

**Update 1:** Shown complete data

```
var data = {
   id: 5,
   name: 'Bilbo Baggins',
   age: '27',
   // This data below must be persisted in another table that has a relationship of n .. n because another Hobbits can live in those addresses.
   streetaddress1: 'The Shire',
   stnumber1: '112',
   streetaddress2: 'Valfenda',
   stnumber2: '42'
};

$.post('/editHim', data, function(returnedData) {
   followTheDragonWithTheRing(returnedData);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you create a Data class which models the data structure

```
public class Data {
  String id;
  String name;
  String age;

  // getters/setters
}
```

you can then receive it in your entry method

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String editHim(Data data) {
  return "data[" + data.getId() + ',' + data.getName() + ',' + data.getAge() + ']';
}
```

you can produce JSON in the same pattern using the return value of the method.

**Update:**

Considering the addresses issue, I think the data would be more clearly structured as

```
var data = {
   id: 5,
   name: 'Bilbo Baggins',
   age: '27',
   // This data below must be persisted in another table that has a relationship of n .. n because another Hobbits can live in those addresses.
   addresses: [{
       streetaddress: 'The Shire',
       stnumber: '112'
     },{
       streetaddress: 'Valfenda',
       stnumber: '42'
     }
  ]
};
```

the corresponding entities on the server side:

```
@Entity
public class Data {
  @Id
  String id;
  String name;
  String age;
  @ManyToMany
  List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

  // getters/setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Address {
  String streetaddress;
  String stnumber;

  // getters/setters
}
```

Comment: I have data that provide 2 pojo informations. Any another idea?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I assume you are looking for solutions for the server side. What have you tried? Is the method called with different data structures?

Comment: The solution must be at server side. But the JSON that is posted to server has data to fill 2 data structures(means models). I think there are another way instead of create another class to handle all data and after that, separate it into 2 models to be persisted.

Comment: can you update your question with an example of the data you want to post? as far as i understand, you want to send the nested structure (2 non-primitive objects inside an object), is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

if the string being returned is in json string format you can use eval function example:

```
returnedData = eval('('+returnedData+')');
```

so if the value of the returned data is something like ['id':1,'test':2] it will then be converted into an object allowing you to access it like this:

```
alert(returnedData['id']);
```